# Reading data to multidimensional array

Tags: vb.net

I have to read data from database to multidimensional array of unknown size.

```
    Dim myarray As String()

            Using reader = mcmd.ExecuteReader()
                While (reader.Read())

                    myarray = TryCast(reader("mydataarray"), String())

                End While
            End Using
```

Here I got in myarray array of strings of last readed row only.

How to get that in 'myarray' will be readed data of all rows from sql result?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Would it not be better to get a list of a typed class based upon your data? What possible benefit do you get from putting it into a string array?

Comment: P.S, you are writing the each row, to the array... and keep on replacing it.. you never increment the array, to make more space for the next row? I have never done what you are attempting.. so I'm just guessing here... from looking at your implementation. Rdr.read, executes each row in the reader... row for row..

Comment: Only benefit which can be achieved here is simplicity and speed with functionality enough for my purposes. So, question is not why but how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code to do what I think you mean:

```
Using reader = mcmd.ExecuteReader()
   Dim myOuterList as New List(of String())
   While (reader.Read())
      Dim myInnerList as New List(of String)
      'For loop retrieves all columns of data as string
      For i = 0 to reader.FieldCount - 1
         myInnerList.Add(reader.GetString(i))
      Next
      myOuterList.Add(myInnerList.ToArray)
   End While  
End Using 
dim myarray = myOuterList.ToArray
```

Resulting myarray will be of type `String()()` I.E. a two-dimensional array of strings.

Though this is possible, I would seriously consider using a typed solution as it will be much easier to understand code dealing with a list of a type than a two-dimensional array.

The typed version would be something like this:

```
Dim myList As List(Of myType) = reader.OfType(Of IDataRecord) _
                              .Select(Function(data) New myType _
                                        With {.mydataarray = data.item("mydataarray")})
                                              'Additionaly properties if needed.
```

Comment: Well, consider that all coders havent to write "understandable" code and have different motives in his coding. With your solution we get loop (of reader's data) inside a loop (of reader). With your code is possible to push data into array but I ask, if I can load whole row of data without looping into 'myarray', why wouldn't I be able to read 2 or more rows automatically in two dimensional array?

Comment: You could get all values from an individual row with something like 'dim badVariableName as Object()` `reader.GetValues(badVariableName)` But the values will be typed as object. If you want them to be in an array of strings you'll still need to convert those to strings.

Comment: OK Daniel, thank you for trying to help. I can use some tips of your solutions.